# How to use sed to match Month day year pattern?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am working with large documents and I want to make two tasks, the first is to substitute all the dates that come in this way: "August 12 2014" or "January 31 1999" so I am using the following line in sed:

`s/\(jan.\|feb.\|mar.\|apr.\|may\|jun.\|jul.\|aug.\|sep.\|oct.\|nov.\|dec.\) \([0-9]\|[0-9][0-9]\) [1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/tokendate/g`

However It does not take for example august, I know I could change aug. for august, but I'd like that sed match any string that begins with aug___ or sep____.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please do not combine two questions into one post. Regarding the date regex, are you intentionally escaping the pipe symbol with a backslash? Doing so tells the regex to match an actual pipe character in the string. I suspect you don't want to escape the pipe characters.

Comment: please ask  a single question.

Comment: Sample files would be useful in order to answer the questions also separate questions would help the process too.

Comment: Ok, I will separate both questions.

Comment: Here is the second part, http://stackoverflow.com/q/25167797/997333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -r 's/(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[a-z]* [0-9]{1,2} [1-9][0-9]{3}/tokendate/gi' file`

Comment: thanks, could you check the second part?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/25167797/997333