# How to use sed to match any URL?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace all URLs in a large collection of documents by a single token, however the regular expression I'm doing does not seem to work

`s/www\.[a-z|0-9]*[.a-z]*/urltoken/g`

This would match www.example.com or www.example.com.co. But what if there is another combination of characters or words after that, e.g., www.foo.bar?q=lol or www.regexr.com/index.html?q=bar. I'd like to fit ANY combination of characters after I validate the first part of the url, i.e., www.example.com.co_(Here goes those characters)_, however before encountering a single space. What kind of regexp could fit that in sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed 's/www\.[^ ]*/urltoken/g' file`

Comment: this would match anything that comes after the url that is not a space. That could happen if the url is for example part of html file: `<a href="www.example.com">bruh</a>`